# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource Ruby on Rails 4, Jquery Mobile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-mobile, omniauth-facebook

I am using Jquery Mobile, Ruby on Rails 4 and Omniauth-facebook. When I click on Sing in by Facebook I get this in my console:

```
omniauth: (facebook) Request phase initiated.
```

This is stuck. I checked browser console and it showed me this error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id..... No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access.
```

I have checked online and many people are facing this. But, I have not been to find a comprehensive solution for rails. Please suggest what to do.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? Same problem here...

Comment: No. Did you find anything?

Comment: Yes. For me it was Turbolinks. Deactivating it for this link did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Try disabling Turbolinks for this link:

```
<a href="..." data-no-turbolink>Sign in</a>
```

Comment: Turbolinks are disabled for the entire website.